# Sorting a WPF datagrid by word preceding search word

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a datagrid which i'm trying to sort. The datagrid has a column of strings. On this column I perform filtering by a search string. Once completed i want to sort the datagrid by the word preceding or the word after the search string within the cell. How would i go about sorting like this?

***Update***

Here's what ive got so far.

```
private void tbSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as Textbox;
        _searchstr = tb.Text;
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SentenceLists);
        view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterBySearch);
    }
```

This is the filter function, I was thinking of adding another property to my SentenceLists object called sortWord and sorting on that. But am having trouble getting it to work.

```
private bool FilterBySearch(object item)
    {
        ServiceTemplateController.SentenceList sl = item as ServiceTemplateController.SentenceList;
        if (_searchstr.ToUpper() == "") return true;
        if (sl.sentence.Contains(_searchstr.ToUpper()))
        {
            string[] strArray = sl.sentence.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0 ; i < strArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (strArray[i].Contains(_searchstr.ToUpper()))
                {
                    if (radioBefore.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        if (i == 0) sl.sortWord = strArray[i];
                        else sl.sortWord = strArray[i - 1];
                    }
                    else  //radio after is selected then.
                    {
                        if (i == strArray.Count() - 1) sl.sortWord = strArray[i];
                        else sl.sortWord = strArray[i + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried ...

Comment: Can you please provide us with an example so that we can give a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being pretty easy. Just added another hidden column to the datagrid bound to sortWord. I would then sort by this column using the ICollectionView sortdescriptions.
code below

```
private void tbSearchRun()
    {
        TextBox textbox = tbSearch as TextBox;
        if (textbox != null)
        {
            _searchstr = textbox.Text;
            if (_searchstr == null) return;
            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SentenceLists);
            view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterBySearch);
            view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("sortWord", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            view.Refresh();
        }
    }
private bool FilterBySearch(object item)
    {
        ServiceTemplateController.SentenceList sl = item as ServiceTemplateController.SentenceList;
        if (_searchstr.ToUpper() == "") return true;
        if (sl.sentence.Contains(_searchstr.ToUpper()))
        {
            string[] strArray = sl.sentence.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (strArray[i].Contains(_searchstr.ToUpper()))
                {
                    if (radioBefore.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        if (i == 0) sl.sortWord = strArray[i];
                        else sl.sortWord = strArray[i - 1];
                    }
                    else  //radio after is selected then.
                    {
                        if (i == strArray.Count() - 1) sl.sortWord = strArray[i];
                        else sl.sortWord = strArray[i + 1];
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```